# Is there possibility that a finally block might not execute?

Tags: java, exception

We know that no matter whether an exception is thrown, or caught and handled it, the finally block will get executed, So I was curious that is there any possibility that finally block will not executed.

And if System.exit() is called either in try or catch, then also will the finally gets called?

Comment: If you pull out the plug of your pc, the finally block will not get executed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> If the JVM exits while the `try` or `catch` code is being executed, then the `finally` block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the `try` or `catch` code is interrupted or killed, the `finally` block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.

Source: [java.sun.com: Java Tutorial: The finally Block](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

Comment: take note of the "may" word there.

Answer (score 7):

`System.exit()` will prevent a `finally` block from executing.

Answer (score 3):

In the Java documentation:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

It explains Finally very well.

They do note that if the JVM exits, that the finally block will *not* be called. Or if a thread that is running the block of code gets killed, the finally block will *not* be called. In all other cases it will.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I can think of right now is an `OutOfMemoryError` in which case there is a chance that no further code in your app can be executed.

Comment: Even in case of an OutOfMemoryError, the finally block will be executed. The execution of the finally block itself may then of course cause an OutOfMemoryError itself, but that may also happen, even if the try block completed succesfully.

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    System.out.println("BEFORE");
    System.exit(0);
    System.out.println("AFTER");
} finally {
    System.out.println("FINALLY");
}
```

this will give you the output:

```
BEFORE
```

Answer (score 1):

System.exit(1); you can use

Answer (score 1):

Another situation that I can think of (that is left out from the other answers) is when an `exception` is thrown inside a `finally` block, in that case the `finally` block will not be *"completely"* executed.

Answer (score 0):

If some Java Native Interface method segfaults (a library function outside of java but called from there crashes) a finally method will also not be called because the entire JVM stops.

Errors in the JVM itself also result in a crash and prevent everything from continued execution.

Answer (score 0):

the finally clause in the try-catch exception block always executes, irrespective of the occurrence of exception in the normal java program flow. If the execution flow is stopped before the finally clause then the finally block will not be executed.

we can use `System.exit(1);` before finally block and stop the execution flow of the program.